# Hybrid GPU on Lenovo G40-80

Tags: intel-graphics, lenovo, 17.10, gpu-driver, amdgpu

I have the Lenovo G40-80 notebook and it comes with the Radeon R5 M230 and the Intel Core i5-5200U. At Windows, it's designed to activate the AMD GPU when the notebook it's connected to the charger, and when I disconnect it from the charger the AMD GPU turn off and the Intel Graphics activates itself. But at Ubuntu, this doesn't happen, the system only uses the Intel Graphics. What should I do to have the same system that works at Windows?

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display' output:

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo HD Graphics 5500
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
04:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
    Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the system have only detected the Intel Graphics`? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Information added

Comment: The system detects both adapters.

Comment: But how do i do this "If you want to run some application on the AMD adapter, you can tun it with DRI_PRIME=1 prefix."? I wanna play some games i have on steam with my amd gpu

Comment: There is a lot of questions and answers about switching graphics. You can run steam in a terminal with this prefix, or set it permanently for steam in the program shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your system detects both AMD and Intel adapters.

By default the Intel is used. There is no need to use the AMD adapter for every application even if your laptop is on AC power. It doesn't add any value.

If you want to run some application on the AMD adapter, you can run it with `DRI_PRIME=1` prefix.

If you want to run Steam games with the AMD GPU you can change the Steam shortcut in `/usr/share/applications` to

```
DRI_PRIME=1 /usr/games/steam %U
```

Another way is to run Steam in a terminal by `DRI_PRIME=1 steam`.

Comment: How can i change the shortcut? Only root can.

Comment: You can use `sudo` to get root privileges.

Comment: But i do this at terminal or nautilus?

Comment: In 17.10 you can't run graphical apps like nautilus with `sudo`. You can do it e.g. by `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop`. Edit the `Exec=/usr/games/steam %U` to `DRI_PRIME=1 /usr/games/steam %U`

Comment: You do it in a terminal.

Comment: I changed it but now when i try to execute it says there is an error

Comment: How do you execute, and what is the error? Maybe you did some wrong edit. There is a space after `1`.

Comment: I changed and clicked on the Steam icon at /usr/share/applications, and says "There was an error lauching the application"

Comment: And yeah, i put a space after the 1

Comment: Don't run it from there. Run it as you did before. And also spell check your edit.

Comment: [Desktop Entry]
Name=Steam
Comment=Application for managing and playing games on Steam
Exec=DRI_PRIME=1 /usr/games/steam %U
Icon=steam
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;FileTransfer;Game;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/steam;
Actions=Store;Community;Library;Servers;Screenshots;News;Settings;BigPicture;Friends;
Keywords=Games

Comment: Oh, and now doesnt show the Steam shortcut when i click at "Show applications"

Comment: Maybe do `Exec='DRI_PRIME=1 /usr/games/steam %U'`. I don't use 17.10. Maybe there are some tricks there.

Comment: I still get errors

Comment: Search by `how to run steam with DRI_PRIME=1` in google.

Comment: I wont run steam with the AMD GPU, but the games. I've just saw there is an option to run the game with the AMD GPU here: https://forum.manjaro.org/t/amd-not-loaded-with-steam-how-to-use-prime/32215/2

Comment: Just one more question, how can i verify if the game is really runing on my AMD GPU?

Comment: There must be some steam console. I don't know exactly.